# Python filter script

Tags: python, linux

In my ftp server contain a log file record all download records, i want to using Python get this file and output a simplified file which contain records in latest one week or 7 days.
The log file like .. in  /CliMb/xxx.

```
Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12461] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12460] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon     password "gxxglxxxxt@google.com"
Sat Jun  2 03:32:14 2012 [pid 12462] [ftp] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "66.249.68.236",   "/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100022/readme.txt", 451 bytes, 1.39Kbyte/sec
Sat Jun  2 03:32:22 2012 [pid 12677] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
Sat Jun  2 03:32:23 2012 [pid 12676] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon password "xxxxxbot@google.com"
Sat Jun  2 03:35:27 2012 [pid 12706] [ftp] FAIL DOWNLOAD: Client "66.2
```

Thanks.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i didn't know about python, now i start learning python, so can you give me some advice to solve this question.

Comment: break up the problem into smaller tasks: how to read/write a file/stream in Python, how to extract a date in given format from a string (or (more complex) how to compare dates without converting them to datetime object first).

Comment: Thanks, can you give me some examples about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
lines = []
with open("somelog.txt") as f:
      lines = [line for line in f]
def OnlyRecent(line):
      return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %h:%m:%s %Y") < (time.time()-(60*60*24*5)) #5 days old
print "\n".join(filter(OnlyRecent,lines))
```

something like that at least...

Comment: Thanks, how can i read it from server like a log file in /usr/bin

Comment: ummm write it to a file? `with open("somefile.txt","w") as f: f.write("\n".join(filter(OnlyRecent,lines))`   ... this is basic basic basic python ... I would look at JF Sebastians link above... I dont want to write all your code for you ... there are free lancers who will do that for a fee for you ;)

Comment: when i using this return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %h:%m:%s %Y") < (time.time()-(60*60*24*5)), it has some error. someone say the return type is wrong